# Pass value from input field from one component to another as a const

Tags: reactjs

Here's the architecture:

1. Input component receives text and exports it as a const string.
2. Concatenate component imports Input's const string, then concatenates it between 2 more consts to create a distinct URL as a new const. This new const (the URL) is exported as a string.
3. Datafetch component imports the Concatenate const and uses it to fetch data from an API. It receives data from the API as an object, parses that data and displays a specific part of it as a string o text in a div.
4. These three components are all also imported to the App component which renders everything in a browser.
5. There's also an Output component, which I pass the Datafetch component into

I've got everything working with the three static strings declared as constants in the Concatenate component, but I want to use the new functionality from the Input component to make the second (of 3 constants) dynamic. This will allow a user to enter specific text into the input field which is captured as a string and create a unique URL.

Answer (score 0):

In order to achieve it you will need to handle the change / state on `URLconcatenate` component, and pass the onChange or onClick handler as a prop to the `Inputfield` compoennt.
Example:
*notice im using useState - in order to update the dom when we are setting the value.

```
import {useState} from 'react'
import Inputfield from './Inputfield';


function URLconcatenate() {
const [value, setValue] = useState('')
const part1 = 'www.'
const part3 = '.com'
const urlString = part1 + value + part3

const onClickHandler = (val) => {
 setValue(val)
}
    return (
        <div>
            <Inputfield onClickHandler={onClickHandler} />
            {urlString}
        </div>
    )
}

export default URLconcatenate
```

and the input component will look like this:
here im getting the onClickHandler prop and firing it in the on click event (in the button click)

```
import { useState } from 'react';

function Inputfield({onClickHandler}) {
    const [value, setValue] = useState("");

    return (
        <div>
            <input type="text" onChange={(e) => setValue(e.target.value)} />
            <br />
            <button
                onClick={
                    () => onClickHandler(value)
                }>Get input value</button>
        </div>
    );
}

export default Inputfield
```

Codesandbox example here:
https://codesandbox.io/p/devbox/cool-mountain-ngsrxl

So to get a value from a child component, we need to have on the parent component handler / state and to pass them to the child component. the child component will fire the onChange or you can simply pass the setState directly to the child component, and this way you can access the value on the parent compoennt.

Important to say: i modified the code using your code. it might be a cleaner / better way to achieve the same. but i wanted to use exactly your code and to do as least changes possible in order to keep your original code.

Comment: Thank you for your advice, I have one more function that I want to add, I had previously set up the URLconcatenate component to export const URLString but now I can't export it…

Comment: what do you mean? can you add an example to your question?

Comment: Sure! In the original code I shared above, note the // export const urlString = part1 + part2 + part3 // I use that const final to pass / export the concatenated string to another component that executes a fetch function, it's essential to the key functionality of the app. Another way to ask my question is: once I get the concatenated string (from the method you provided to get the input text field to work) how can I export it as a new const (like how I originally did from the 3 static consts I showed) …

Comment: where do you need to import this const ? in many places in the app? or specific place? if you can share more infomation about how you are using the const `urlString`it will be easier to know what solution will work the best for you.

Comment: Please see above, I am revising my question to provide more detail… Hopefully this makes the entire effort more clear…